# CMake debug and release names of static library in find

Tags: cmake

first of all, this is my first time ever writing cmake files so I'll need baby explanation, thanks for the consideration.

Basically I'm writing a static library (e.g. "MyLib"). The release library name is "mylib.lib" and the debug library name is "mylib-d.lib". At this point I'm trying to write the FindMyLib.cmake file for the library's users and I can't figure out how to get CMake to pick the correct one according to the build configuration of the library's user.

The environment is Windows/MSVC with a Linux version down the road.

This is how my file looks right now -

```
find_library(MYLIB_LIBRARY 
NAMES 
    "mylib" "libmylib"
PATHS
    ${LOCAL_LIB_PATH}
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    /usr/
    /usr/bin/
    /usr/include/
    /usr/lib/
    /usr/local/
    /usr/local/bin/
    /opt/)

find_path(MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR 
NAMES 
    mylib.h
PATHS
    ${LOCAL_INCLUDE_PATH}/mylib/
    /usr/
    /usr/bin/
    /usr/include/
    /usr/lib/
    /usr/local/
    /usr/local/bin/
    /opt/)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(MySQL DEFAULT_MSG MYLIB_LIBRARY MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)

message(STATUS "MYLIB_FOUND: ${MYLIB_FOUND}")
message(STATUS "MYLIB_LIBRARY: ${MYLIB_LIBRARY}")
message(STATUS "MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR: ${MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR}")

if (${MYLIB_FOUND})
link_libraries(${MYLIB_LIBRARY})
include_directories(${MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR}/../)
endif()
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you are learning cmake here are some resources: https://discourse.cmake.org/t/recommended-cmake-tutorials/2966

Answer (score 1):

> At this point I'm trying to write the FindMyLib.cmake file for the
> library's users and I can't figure out how to get CMake to pick the
> correct one according to the build configuration of the library's user.

The `Find<lib>.cmake` modules are intended for use with libraries that don't themselves provide CMake config files. The preferred way for libraries to be found is through CMake config files, which CMake makes pretty straight-forward to generate.

You first need to add an export set name when installing your library targets:

```
include(GNUInstallDirs) # makes the CMAKE_INSTALL_<dir> variables available

install(
  TARGETS MyLib
  EXPORT MyLib_Targets  # this is an arbitrary identifier later used
                        # for the creation of the config files
  RUNTIME
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR} # where to install DLLs on Windows
  LIBRARY
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} # where to install the .lib file on 
                                        # Windows and the .so files on Linux
  ARCHIVE
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} # where to install .a / .lib files 
                                        # for static builds
  INCLUDES 
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR} # where the headers for the
                                            # library will be installed
)
```

Note that the `INCLUDES` option in the `install` command above doesn't actually install anything, it is only used to correctly set the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property for the imported targets in the generated CMake config file. You'll manually have to install all the headers, e.g. by doing

```
install(
  DIRECTORIES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)
```

if you have a dedicated top-level folder named `include` that contains all public headers.

All the steps until this point you probably have already implemented for your library (apart from setting the `EXPORT` option when installing the library targets).

The config files themselves can be generated with

```
install(
  EXPORT MyLib_Targets # refers to the identifier specified in 
                       # the previous `install` command
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/MyLib # there are a few different 
                                                  # directories in which CMake
                                                  # will search for config files, 
                                                  # this is one of the more common ones
  NAMESPACE MyLib::  # Users will consume your library via `MyLib::MyLib`
  FILE MyLib-Targets.cmake
)
```

In very simple cases where your library does not itself have external dependencies you can replace the `MyLib-Targets.cmake` with `MyLibConfig.cmake` and everything will work already.

If you do have external dependencies you'll have to create a separate config file that first searches for these dependencies and then includes the generated config file. For example, if your library depends on `libz` you'll have a config file template "MyLibConfig.cmake.in" in a `cmake` directory with content

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@

include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
find_dependencies(ZLIB)

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/MyLib-Targets.cmake)
```

and use

```
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
configure_package_config_file(
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/MyLibConfig.cmake.in # path to the template file
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibConfig.cmake    # path where the generated config file 
                                                   # will be located
  INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/MyLib # where you'll later install  
                                                          # the generated MyLibConfig.cmake 
                                                          # file
  INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
)
```

in your `CMakeLists.txt` to fill in the template.

As a last step you'll need to install the this file next to the generated `MyLib-Targets.cmake` file:

```
install(
  FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibConfig.cmake
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/MyLib
)
```

If you now install both a release and debug build into the same prefix it'll automatically pick the release binaries when a consumer builds a release build and the debug libs otherwise.

If you like you can also add version info to your config file so that consumers can specify that they need a compatible version. To do so use

```
write_basic_package_version_file(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibConfigVersion.cmake
  VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}     # assumes you set a version in the `project` call. 
                                 # you can also just hard-code a version number here
  COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion # assuming you follow SemVer. Alternatives are 
                                 # AnyNewerVersion, SameMinorVersion and ExactVersion
)
```

and install the file by calling

```
install(
  FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibConfigVersion.cmake
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/MyLib
)
```